# MySQL Workbench "Case" Statement Giving Error

Tags: mysql, workbench, case-statement

I am working on MySql Workbench, and using the following case statement which shows error.

ErrorCode: 1064 you have an error in your SQL syntax: check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near.....

```
select id, name, percentage,
 CASE
    WHEN PERCENTAGE >= 80 AND <= 100 THEN "Merit"
    WHEN PERCENTAGE >= 50 AND < 79 THEN "1st Division"
    WHEN PERCENTAGE >= 45 AND < 60 THEN "2nd Division"
    WHEN PERCENTAGE >= 33 AND < 45 THEN "3rd Division"
    WHEN PERCENTAGE < 33 THEN "Fail"
ELSE "Not Correct %"
END AS Grade
from student2;
```

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: your case statement doesn't cover 79 and overlaps on 50 to 59 (not the issue; just a hint)

Comment: I'd recommend you to create percentage ranges table instead of hardcoding and join it. This will make your query more clear and will allow the ranges to be editable or even dynamic (you may store a lot of different lists in a table and specify needed one).

Answer (score 0):

The condition like this is not valid. The second comparison (after `AND`) also need a column:

```
 WHEN PERCENTAGE >= 80 AND <= 100 THEN
```

You can use the following instead:

```
 WHEN PERCENTAGE >= 80 AND PERCENTAGE <= 100 THEN

 -- or (if >= AND <=)
 WHEN PERCENTAGE BETWEEN 80 AND 100 THEN
```

The correct query:

```
SELECT id, name, percentage,
  CASE
    WHEN PERCENTAGE BETWEEN 80 AND 100 THEN "Merit"
    WHEN PERCENTAGE >= 50 AND PERCENTAGE < 79 THEN "1st Division"
    WHEN PERCENTAGE >= 45 AND PERCENTAGE < 60 THEN "2nd Division"
    WHEN PERCENTAGE >= 33 AND PERCENTAGE < 45 THEN "3rd Division"
    WHEN PERCENTAGE < 33 THEN "Fail"
ELSE "Not Correct %" END AS Grade
FROM student2;
```

Comment: Thanks very much Mr. Sabastian your input solved my problem.